# Combine a List of Plots: Using MapThread with Show

Tags: plotting, graphics, map

I have a list of graphics

```
p1 = Plot[x Sin[x] - 1, {x, -2.5, 2.5}]
p2 = Plot[Evaluate[D[x Sin[x] - 1, x]], {x, -2.5, 2.5},PlotStyle -> Red]
ListNew = {p1, p2};
```

I can use Show to combine them:

```
Show[p1,p2]
```

I can also use MapThread if I understand correctly here:

```
MapThread[f,{x1,x2}] = f[x1,x2]
```

But I dont understand why using MapThread with Show wont work?

```
MapThread[Show,ListNew]
```

Comment: You want `Apply` not `MapThread`.

Comment: `MapThread` is for mapping a multivariate function over multiple ***lists*** of arguments, not for applying such a function to a sequence of arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MapThread does not work the way you believe.  Run your actual code:

```
 MapThread[f,{x1,x2}]
```

You get an error message: "Object x1 at position {2,1} in MapThread[f,{x1,x2}] has only 0 of required 1 dimensions."  Basically, you are being told that MapThread wants Lists as the elements in the second argument. Your expression x1 is not a List nor is x2, nor is p1 or p2. As stated in the documentation under Possible Issues: "All arguments must be lists of the same length." (Although, as set forth in the documentation, MapThread can also work with Associations).